# Three questions about Store in Flux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flux, reactjs-flux

Following [the flux concepts](https://github.com/facebook/flux/tree/master/examples/flux-concepts) we can get the next assertions for which I couldn't find explanations.

> Every store will receive every action.

**Why?** My suggestion: since a **store** contents some business-logic we have to provide it with all possible changes and data so the store can decide what to do with them on its own.

> The data in a store must only be mutated by responding to an action.

**Why?** My suggestion: the reason is violation of unidirectional data-flow in case of not responding to an action.

> Every time a store's data changes it must emit a "change" event.

**Why?** *I can't get this point.*

Comment: I'm not sure I could catch you. But I meant there is unidirectional violation when we mutate data not by responding to an action. For example: a setter.

Comment: Thanks for the clearance. I've edited the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flux is just a way of managing the data flow of your application, so it is up to the developer to make sure this actually happens. But I'll try to paint a picture of *why* these concepts are a part of Flux.

> Every store will receive every action.

If you have only one dispatcher in your application, every store will listen to actions dispatched through that dispatcher. It is up to you whether or not the store should act on the action dispatched, but to be able to react on it the store *has to know of it*.

Not all actions should lead to changes in a store, though. But the dispatcher simply doesn't care, because it won't know anything about the store implementation. It's just telling all stores that *this action happened, do what you want with it or go on with your life without caring*.

> The data in a store must only be mutated by responding to an action.

You're right that doing it with a different approach could be violation of unidirectional data-flow. Doing things this way makes sure all parts of your application has the correct state based on the actions that happens.

By not doing it this way you would let go of one of the flux strengths. Update your store based on dispatched actions, and other stores will also be aware that the action happened, and thereby react to it if they want to. If you update the store directly you will end up having no clear picture of what parts of your application that are altering the state of your store.

> Every time a store's data changes it must emit a "change" event.

People often describe the stores in a flux application as the *source of truth*. When a store's data changes, the basis for the visualization of your data changes. You want to be confident that if my store holds a certain value, this is what my application uses as it's data.

It's related to the first quote here. The store doesn't know if a listener depends on it's data. By emitting a change, it will let all listeners know that *hey, I changed. Make sure you have all my latest changes*. If you don't emit change, the listener could end up displaying something based on old data.

---

All of these  statements are related to the same thing: **If an action happens in your application, don't make any assumptions about which part of your application that wants to know the details of it.** Make sure everyone can act on it, if they want to.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. It sounds like you really deeply understand flux architecture. However I can suggest you are not the author of flux architecture. Therefore I'd like to see here proof links of what you described that is similar to the truth and not states the truth. So where can I find Facebook's claims of the described concepts?

Comment: Oh, sorry if I misunderstood your question. 

I'm actually not sure if faceebook provides any precise descriptions for the concepts. I guess they leave a lot of it open to the user as they try to make it clear that it's just a pattern.

Personally I went through quite a bit of daily work with Flux before I got up to speed with _why_. My answer above is mostly just based on a lot of try/fail, tutorials and opinions in the community.